# Survey papers on Natural Language Understanding

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, statistics, machine-learning-model

What are some good survey or review papers on the state of the art of machine learning approaches to grammatical/syntactic structure of natural languages?

Answer (score 2):

“[Grammar as a foreign language](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7449)” (2015) by Vinyals et al. is not a review paper but is a significant breakthrough by applying sequence-to-sequence deep learning.

"[Advances in natural language processing](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/349/6245/261)" (2015) by Hirschberg and Manning provides a general overview, including parsing.

"[Recent Trends in Deep Learning Based Natural Language Processing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8416973)" (2018) by Young et al. covers popular deep learning approaches and lists current benchmarks for parsing.